# Sharing ground with the outlet power source

Tags: gpio

So, here's the theoretical setup:
220V outlet to which a 5V USB power source is connected, powering the RPI.
That outlet powers some other 220V consumers (such as a lightbulb).

Lets say I have a GPIO set as input (pullup resistor), will connecting the ground straight from the outlet to the GPIO input do any harm? Will it work and detect when the ground is connected?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: You know hooking a Pi up to 220V is going to fry it? I assume your setup is slightly different to how you have described it. Why not power the Pi through the micro USB port?

Answer (score 2):

A few things to consider:

- Low voltage power supplys (such as cell phone chargers, 5V supplies for the Pi, Laptop power supplies) are typically completely isolated from the 230 V outlet socket. They therefore typically do not share GND with
- PC power supplies on the other hand are grounded which will in a PC setup (using the PC's USB sockets) connect the USB GND (and therefore the Pi's GND) with PE (protective earth)
- in neither cases should any of those GND be connected to N (neutral) of the 230 V socket
- last but not least: if you have to ask these questions I would not consider it safe for you to play around with 230V. This **really is potential life threatening danger** and not to be taken lightly.

> So, here's the theoretical setup: 220V outlet to which a 5V USB power source is connected, powering the RPI. That outlet powers some other 220V consumers (such as a lightbulb).

This calls for a relay that completely isolates your low power circuit (the Pi) from the 230 V. Consider that (for all intents and purposes) the two contacts of the lightbulb are potentially at 230 V since the plug could be put in the socket both ways in most systems (you would not know which is the "*safe*" neutral pin and which is "hot".

So again, think twice before tinkering with 230 V.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting anything to the Ground pin of a GPO is potentially dangerous in the event of anything else on the circuit having a fault. DO NOT DO THIS. In some circumstances even a fault on a neighbouring property can cause problems.

Also it wouldn't work because you have no reference voltage.

PS To forestall comments by others unused to power wiring. In a MEN power system the Neutral is connected to local Ground in the switchboard. The Ground SHOULD be very low resistance (but quite often is not), BUT if large fault currents flow there can be significant voltage. Even the voltage drop in the power utility Neutral can cause significant current to flow in the connection to ground.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question.

It is possible in some ways but not by going trough your board.

In my case I use outer voltage source for motors and supply higher voltage to them using a H-Bridge. Or you might want to take a look at transistor.

Its like an electronic switch that you activate with the board to let higher voltage in another circuit.

And even with the right set-up there are security mesure to be taken for you and your equipment. So beware. An electronic timer for light probably contain's all you need.